# I've a list of files - resulted from find command, how can I use it to zip/tar the files and delete the original files

Tags: files, rm, zip

I have a list of files from the `find` command. How can I zip/tar the files and delete the original files?
The results are from: `find . -type f -exec egrep "mxprod|nlsoprdc" {}  /dev/null \;`; how can I zip the file and delete the originals?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU tools, you can do:

```
find . -type f -exec grep --null -El 'mxprod|nlsoprdc' {} + |
  tar --xz -cf /path/to/file.tar.xz --remove-files --null -T -
```

Though for that particular usage of `find`, you could do away with it and use GNU `grep`'s `-r`.

```
grep -r --null -El 'mxprod|nlsoprdc' . |
  tar --xz -cf /path/to/file.tar.xz --remove-files --null -T -
```

Note that the directories the found files are in are not added as members of the archive. They will be recreated upon extracting the archive, but not with the original metadata (ownership, permissions, ACLs, other attributes...) of the original ones.

You could address that by doing:

```
grep -r --null -El 'mxprod|nlsoprdc' . |
  awk -F/ -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '{
    p=""; sep=""
    for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
      p = p sep $i; sep=FS
      if (! (p in dirs)) {
        print p
        dirs[p]
      }
    }
    print}' |
  tar --xz -cf /path/to/file.tar.xz --no-recursion --remove-files --null -T -
```

Though you'll see errors about the directories that `tar` can't remove as they're not empty.

In any case, note that it's dangerous in that if for instance the file system gets full, `xz` could fail to write the output for a given file after `tar` has already removed it.

It may be better to start removing files only after you've made sure that archive has properly been created.